# Flutter local json

Tags: json, flutter, local

I copy this [file](https://support.oneskyapp.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/202761727/example_2.json) in my local and try to parse it.
The following are my questions in mind:

- 1) how to parse the categories [sport, maths] for listview purpose/
- 2) how to parse item inside the category?
- 3) does it need to change    the format of the json to have simpler codes?

Currently, this is the code

```
Future<dynamic> _future;

  Future<String> _getJson() async {
    var response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/example_2.json');
    var decodedJason = json.decode(response);
    return (decodedJason);   }

  void initState() {
    _future = _getJson();
    super.initState();   }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should check below link
https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/11/flutter-how-to-parse-local-json-file-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Add Your JSON File To The pubspec.yaml

```
 assets:
    - assets/example_2.json
```

And Then You Can Use rootBundle To Load & Display It

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/config.json');
}
```

Make A Sure Json File Is Not Empty?